# Get multiple element value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**code**

HTML

```
    <table>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_0" value="105" quantity="1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_1" value="155" quantity="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_2" value="15" quantity="7"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

<a id="button-generate" class="button" style="">Generate</a>
```

**Question:**

The above code is that html store with the data value, so how can I using java script to store the value data into Array once the user click the generate button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#button-generate").on("click", function(){

  var values = $('input').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('value');
  }).toArray();
  
  console.log(values);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_0" value="105" quantity="1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_1" value="155" quantity="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_2" value="15" quantity="7"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

<a id="button-generate" class="button" style="">Generate</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

if you re using jquery, maybe you can try this:

```js
$("#button-generate").on("click", function(){

  var vall = [];
  $.each($("input[name^='zxc_']"), function(){            
    vall.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(vall);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_0" value="105" quantity="1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_1" value="155" quantity="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="zxc_2" value="15" quantity="7"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

<a id="button-generate" class="button" style="">Generate</a>
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/